# Extra parameters passed to parent construct $directoryHelper

Tags: magento2, overrides, construct

I am getting the following error on di compile:

```
**Extra parameters passed to parent construct $directoryHelper**
```

That's the original code:

```
class PreviewButton extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    
    protected $blockFactory;
   
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
        array $data = [],
        ?SecureHtmlRenderer $jsonHelper = null,
        ?DirectoryHelper $directoryHelper = null
    ) {
        $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data, $jsonHelper, $directoryHelper);
    }
```

i extended it and my construct is :

```
class PreviewButton extends OriginalPreviewButton
{
    protected $_directoryHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
        array $data = [],
        ?SecureHtmlRenderer $jsonHelper = null,
        ?DirectoryHelper $directoryHelper = null
    ) {
        OriginalPreviewButton::__construct($context, $blockFactory, $data, $jsonHelper);
        $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;

    }
```

but i am still getting the same error. Can someone help to fix the error? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the **'$data' array** to last param as given below.

```
 class PreviewButton extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field {
    
    protected $blockFactory;
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
        SecureHtmlRenderer $jsonHelper = null,
        DirectoryHelper $directoryHelper = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work unfortunately.

Comment: @Someguy Please try it now answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
class PreviewButton extends OriginalPreviewButton
{
    protected $_directoryHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
        array $data = [],
        ?SecureHtmlRenderer $jsonHelper = null,
        ?DirectoryHelper $directoryHelper = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data, $jsonHelper, $directoryHelper);
        $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your "base" class constructor when you are calling its parent method:

```php
class PreviewButton extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    protected $blockFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
        array $data = [],
        ?SecureHtmlRenderer $jsonHelper = null,
        ?DirectoryHelper $directoryHelper = null
    ) {
        $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data, $jsonHelper, $directoryHelper); // here
    }
}
```

As I can see from this class on Magento 2.4.6, it has a different set of arguments:

```php
class Field extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template implements
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Renderer\RendererInterface
{
    /**
     * @var SecureHtmlRenderer
     */
    private $secureRenderer;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param array $data
     * @param SecureHtmlRenderer|null $secureRenderer
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        array $data = [],
        ?SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->secureRenderer = $secureRenderer ?? ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SecureHtmlRenderer::class);
    }
}
```

You get an error on the `$directoryHelper` (4th argument when only 3 exist in the original class). Try to change your "base" class code to this one, run `setup:di:compile` and test:

```php
class PreviewButton extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    protected $blockFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
        array $data = [],
        ?SecureHtmlRenderer $jsonHelper = null,
        ?DirectoryHelper $directoryHelper = null
    ) {
        $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data); // changed
    }
}
```